# How to enter decimal/binary numbers when creating byte objects in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.1.1.

I know that I can create byte objects using the byte literal in the form of b'...'. In these byte objects, each byte can be represented as a character(in ascii code if I'm not wrong) or as a hexadecimal/octal number. Hexadecimal and octal numbers can be entered using an escape of \x for hexadecimal numbers and just a \ for octal numbers.

However, there's no escape sequences for decimal or binary numbers. Is there any way to enter them into byte objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in [bytes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytes) constructor to turn a sequence of integers into a byte string:

```
>>> bytes((7,8,9,10,11))
b'\x07\x08\t\n\x0b'
>>> bytes(range(7,12))
b'\x07\x08\t\n\x0b'
>>> bytes((0b1,0b0,0b1))
b'\x01\x00\x01'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was trying to do. I completely forgot about using these type of functions to initialise variables.

Answer (score 2):

You could use binary literals for integers

```
>>> b = bytearray(b'abc')
>>> b[0] = 0b1001 # `9` decimal (TAB)
>>> b
bytearray(b'\tbc')
```